# Computational cost of type inference / IntelliSense

Tags: typescript, intellisense, type-inference

When I have a computationally heavy (e.g. deeply recursive) `type Heavy<T extends {}>` - heavy for static type inference at build time I mean - , and e.g. a class like follows:

```
class MyClass<T extends {}> {
  public m1(): Heavy<T>;
  public m2(): Heavy<T>;
  // ...
  public mn(): Heavy<T>;
}
```

will the speed of IntelliSense (that is how long it takes to resolve all types) depend on `n` (the number of methods like shown above) or not?

In other words, will `Heavy<T>` be calculated only once or once for each method?

Also I would be thankful if someone could point me to a source where I can learn more about such type inference behavior of TypeScript.